# Cambiar nombres de los botones con React

Tags: reactjs

Hola a todos tengo un inconveniente a la hora de ejecutar un boton.

La cuestión es que lo tengo programado, que cuando se realice el click, se oculta y genera un link, pero a su vez necesitaría que otros 2 botones que se encuentran cambien su nombre (cuando se realiza el !step)

Los botones serian `button.packageSingleReturn` y `button.packageMultiReturn` que los llamaría con el translate en su respectivo json.

```
return (
        <div className="createPackage">
            <div className="infoContainer">
                <div className="infoHead">
                    <h3>{translate('subtitle.selectPackaging')}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="infoBody">
                    <p>{translate('message.assignPackageFromPrevious')}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="selectPackaging">
                <**Button
                    className="selectPackagingBtn"
                    type="2"
                    disabled={!packages.length}
                    onClick={() => handleSingleReturn()}>
                    {translate('button.packageSingleReturn')}
                </Button>
                <Button
                    className="selectPackagingBtn"
                    type="2"
                    disabled={!packages.length}
                    onClick={() => handleMultipleReturn()}>
                    {translate('button.packageMultiReturn')}
                </Button>**
                {
                    !step &&
                    <Button
                        className="selectPackagingBtn"
                        type="2"
                        onClick={() => dispatch(setCreatePackagesStep())} >
                        {translate('button.configureUnits')}
                    </Button>
                }
            </div>
            **<div className="mt-5">
                <Link className={!step ? 'd-none' : ''} onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
                    <Icon content="arrow-left" height="13px" color="#099AD6" className="mr-2" />
                    {translate('button.back')}
                </Link>
            </div>**
```

Comment: Puedes publicar tus funciones también?